# How can we check the whole sql database for login username and password in mvc3 c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I have more than one table in my sql server database. Each table is for each users named developers, designers, users and so on. My home page contains a login screen. When a user tries to login with their username and password, then it automatically checks whether the username and password belongs to the database. If yes, it redirects to a page, else prompts an error.

I need whole database check instead of one table because there is only one login page for all users. Thanks!

Comment: can't you just include multiple tables in your query, i.e. SELECT Foo FROM Bar, Laa WHERE username='' and password='' or create a view over the multiple tables would perhaps be a 'nicer' approach

Comment: I guess you could `UNION` the tables into a single query.  Perhaps even as a view.  Or use a stored procedure which itself checks multiple tables.  Or make multiple queries to the database until a login is found.  But the real question is... Why on earth are you storing login information in multiple tables in the first place?  A relational database should have, well, a relational structure.  Not just haphazardly place data in a variety of tables.

Comment: Yeah to further Davids comment, it would make more sense to have a user table and then relate to different "profiles"

Comment: This way, a designer can also be a developer and that scenario would be nicely handled

Comment: tbh your architecture is silly and redundant.What happens when you decide to add a different type of user? Create a new table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all to concat multiple results:

```
select displayname, passwd from developers where username = ?
union all
select displayname, passwd from users where username = ?
```

You might want to consider a view in the database, concating them all together with a 'profile' column:

```
create view all_users 
as
select displayname, passwd, 'developer' profile from developers
union all
select displayname, passwd, 'user' from users
```

Comment: how can it perform in a MVC..suppose I have 3 tables.named distributor,dealer,user.I need to perform the login of user with their own username and password in home page.if he tries to login then it automatically check the provided username and password in the database.how van we write the code for that in controller and view page in mvc3?